# Errors in "editconfigs" step in building kernel

Tags: 16.04, kernel

I am trying to build the `linux kernel 4.4.0` using the following steps:

```
Step 1) apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
Step 2) chmod a+x debian/scripts/*
Step 3) chmod a+x debian/scripts/misc/*
Step 4) fakeroot debian/rules clean
Step 5) fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs
Step 6) fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic
```

But at the end of `Step 5)` after I edited the configuration for `i386/config.flavour.generic` to enable i2c support for slave eeprom and said `No` to rest of the flavours, I get the following errors:

```
Running config-check for all configurations ...
check-config: /tmp/tmp.jW7xpVEeRa/CONFIGS/amd64-config.flavour.generic: loading config
check-config: /home/manik/ubuntu_kernel/linux-4.4.0/debian.master/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (48 != -): CONFIG_ARM64_VA_BITS policy<{'arm64': '48'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<Cavium ThunderX 2-socket needs a minimum of 41 bits of VA>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_THERM_ADT746X policy<{'powerpc-powerpc-smp': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<LP:#923094>
check-config: 42/44 checks passed -- exit 1
check-config: /tmp/tmp.jW7xpVEeRa/CONFIGS/amd64-config.flavour.lowlatency: loading config
check-config: /home/manik/ubuntu_kernel/linux-4.4.0/debian.master/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (48 != -): CONFIG_ARM64_VA_BITS policy<{'arm64': '48'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<Cavium ThunderX 2-socket needs a minimum of 41 bits of VA>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_THERM_ADT746X policy<{'powerpc-powerpc-smp': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<LP:#923094>
check-config: 42/44 checks passed -- exit 1
check-config: /tmp/tmp.jW7xpVEeRa/CONFIGS/i386-config.flavour.generic: loading config
check-config: /home/manik/ubuntu_kernel/linux-4.4.0/debian.master/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: 44/44 checks passed -- exit 0
check-config: /tmp/tmp.jW7xpVEeRa/CONFIGS/i386-config.flavour.lowlatency: loading config
check-config: /home/manik/ubuntu_kernel/linux-4.4.0/debian.master/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_THERM_ADT746X policy<{'powerpc-powerpc-smp': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<LP:#923094>
check-config: FAIL (48 != -): CONFIG_ARM64_VA_BITS policy<{'arm64': '48'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<Cavium ThunderX 2-socket needs a minimum of 41 bits of VA>
check-config: 42/44 checks passed -- exit 1
check-config: /tmp/tmp.jW7xpVEeRa/CONFIGS/armhf-config.flavour.generic: loading config
check-config: /home/manik/ubuntu_kernel/linux-4.4.0/debian.master/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (n != -): CONFIG_ACPI_CUSTOM_METHOD policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'i386': 'n'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<SECURITY: allows arbitrary execution>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_XEN_ACPI_PROCESSOR policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'i386': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> <boot essential on XEN host>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_EFI_VARS policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'i386': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<EFI boot requirement (d-i) LP:#837332>
check-config: FAIL (n != -): CONFIG_COMPAT_VDSO policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'i386': 'n'}> mark<ENFORCED>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_THERM_ADT746X policy<{'powerpc-powerpc-smp': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<LP:#923094>
check-config: FAIL (48 != -): CONFIG_ARM64_VA_BITS policy<{'arm64': '48'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<Cavium ThunderX 2-socket needs a minimum of 41 bits of VA>
check-config: 38/44 checks passed -- exit 1
check-config: /tmp/tmp.jW7xpVEeRa/CONFIGS/armhf-config.flavour.generic-lpae: loading config
check-config: /home/manik/ubuntu_kernel/linux-4.4.0/debian.master/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_XEN_ACPI_PROCESSOR policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'i386': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> <boot essential on XEN host>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_THERM_ADT746X policy<{'powerpc-powerpc-smp': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<LP:#923094>
check-config: FAIL (n != -): CONFIG_ACPI_CUSTOM_METHOD policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'i386': 'n'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<SECURITY: allows arbitrary execution>
check-config: FAIL (48 != -): CONFIG_ARM64_VA_BITS policy<{'arm64': '48'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<Cavium ThunderX 2-socket needs a minimum of 41 bits of VA>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_EFI_VARS policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'i386': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<EFI boot requirement (d-i) LP:#837332>
check-config: FAIL (n != -): CONFIG_COMPAT_VDSO policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'i386': 'n'}> mark<ENFORCED>
check-config: 38/44 checks passed -- exit 1
check-config: /tmp/tmp.jW7xpVEeRa/CONFIGS/arm64-config.flavour.generic: loading config
check-config: /home/manik/ubuntu_kernel/linux-4.4.0/debian.master/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_XEN_ACPI_PROCESSOR policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'i386': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> <boot essential on XEN host>
check-config: FAIL (n != -): CONFIG_COMPAT_VDSO policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'i386': 'n'}> mark<ENFORCED>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_THERM_ADT746X policy<{'powerpc-powerpc-smp': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<LP:#923094>
check-config: 41/44 checks passed -- exit 1
check-config: /tmp/tmp.jW7xpVEeRa/CONFIGS/ppc64el-config.flavour.generic: loading config
check-config: /home/manik/ubuntu_kernel/linux-4.4.0/debian.master/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (48 != -): CONFIG_ARM64_VA_BITS policy<{'arm64': '48'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<Cavium ThunderX 2-socket needs a minimum of 41 bits of VA>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_EFI_VARS policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'i386': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<EFI boot requirement (d-i) LP:#837332>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_THERM_ADT746X policy<{'powerpc-powerpc-smp': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<LP:#923094>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_DEBUG_SET_MODULE_RONX policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 's390x': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED>
check-config: FAIL (n != -): CONFIG_COMPAT_VDSO policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'i386': 'n'}> mark<ENFORCED>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_DEBUG_RODATA policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED>
check-config: 32/44 checks passed -- exit 1
*** ERROR: 12 config-check failures detected
rm -rf build
```

Comment: relevantly, you had all 44 checks complete. "check-config: 44/44 checks passed -- exit 0". I have same issue when I changed CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG to normal. I would expect check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> though....

Comment: Later in the actual kernel compile, it tried to config against the non-arch config, "check-config: /root/kern/linux-4.4.0-77.98/debian/build/build-generic/.config: loading config" and scored 43/44 with STACKPROTECTOR policy linked above... it is normal for config-check failures in editconfigs though.